# What are these 2 transactions with the same hash and different values?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, transfer

I am browsing some erc20 transactions from a given ethereum address on the Etherscan API module account and action tokentx.
Example [here](https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&address=0x4e83362442b8d1bec281594cea3050c8eb01311c&page=1&offset=100&startblock=0&endblock=27025780&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken) :

Sometime I observe 2 consecutive identical result except regarding the value field

Example :

```
{"blockNumber":"5235102","timeStamp":"1520756570","hash":"0x68768899c47a79ce4b8cb8d91d00034fa9494a0ff48c9cc6bb995ca69a7e7397","nonce":"526","blockHash":"0x5a4a6c0ebe64c98f173f0c3116bda863e4cbdf2c0d22d64b974e9b26685fbacd","from":"0xb69a50f98a49f85fd2042813e1647b02dc43d71f","contractAddress":"0xa65ee5fd259d94294c4ef030d1a62eeb465b9438","to":"0xe29746124c699fd2063235264bd7f188ee24d27a","value":"2836450","tokenName":"Etherball","tokenSymbol":"EBYTE","tokenDecimal":"9","transactionIndex":"7","gas":"6211693","gasPrice":"2000000000","gasUsed":"4140801","cumulativeGasUsed":"4340045","input":"deprecated","confirmations":"9678838"}
{"blockNumber":"5235102","timeStamp":"1520756570","hash":"0x68768899c47a79ce4b8cb8d91d00034fa9494a0ff48c9cc6bb995ca69a7e7397","nonce":"526","blockHash":"0x5a4a6c0ebe64c98f173f0c3116bda863e4cbdf2c0d22d64b974e9b26685fbacd","from":"0xb69a50f98a49f85fd2042813e1647b02dc43d71f","contractAddress":"0xa65ee5fd259d94294c4ef030d1a62eeb465b9438","to":"0xe29746124c699fd2063235264bd7f188ee24d27a","value":"414791","tokenName":"Etherball","tokenSymbol":"EBYTE","tokenDecimal":"9","transactionIndex":"7","gas":"6211693","gasPrice":"2000000000","gasUsed":"4140801","cumulativeGasUsed":"4340045","input":"deprecated","confirmations":"9678838"}
```

I don't know how to interpret this data.
Are these 2 lines belonging to the same transaction since they have the same hash ?
What are these 2 different values ?
Is it only relative to Etherball ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the transaction in your example on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x68768899c47a79ce4b8cb8d91d00034fa9494a0ff48c9cc6bb995ca69a7e7397) I see this transaction makes multiple transfers of erc20 tokens to various address.

It seems that the etherscan endpoint you are querying returns each of these transfers within the same transactions as separate entries in the `result` array; hence there are duplicate entries with different values when it's transferring different amounts to the same address.